# Weird Pointer Address for Individual Struct Data Member

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, pointer-address

I observe some weird behavior today , the code is as follow :

#### The Code :

```
#include <iostream>

struct text
{
    char c;
};

int main(void)
{
    text experim = {'b'};
    char * Cptr = &(experim.c);

    std::cout << "The Value \t: " << *Cptr << std::endl ;
    std::cout << "The Address \t: " << Cptr << std::endl  ; //Print weird stuff

    std::cout << "\n\n";

    *Cptr = 'z';   //Attempt to change the value

    std::cout << "The New Value \t: " << *Cptr <<std::endl ;
    std::cout << "The Address \t: " << Cptr << std::endl ; //Weird address again

    return 0;
}
```

#### The Question :


1.) The only question I have is why `cout theAddress` for the above code would come out some weird value ?

2.)Why I can still change the value of the member `c` by dereferenncing the pointer which has weird address ?

*Thank you.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider fixing the code like this:

```
std::cout << "The Address \t: " << (void *)Cptr << std::endl ;
```

There's a `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const char* s );` that takes a `char*` so you have to cast to `void*` to print an address, not a **string** it "points" to

Answer (score 5):

I think the "weird" stuff shows up because `cout` thinks it's a cstring, i.e. a 0-terminated character array, so it doesn't print the address as you expected. And since your "string" isn't 0-terminated, all it can do is walk the memory until it encounters a `0`. To sum it up, **you're not actually printing the address**.

> Why I can still change the value of the member c by dereferenncing the
>   pointer which has weird address

The address isn't weird, as explained above. In your code `Cptr` points to a valid memory location and you can do pretty much anything you want with it.